# Trying to use UNION ALL to INSERT into temporary table

Tags: php, mysql, insert, union-all

I'm trying to setup a basic search script. It was suggested to insert data from current mysql tables into a temp table to speed the search up.

Here is the code I've got so far:

```
$temp = 'search_' . date('YmdHis'); // name your temp table

$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$temp} (
      `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      `Model` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Make` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Year` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Loc.` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Sale Price` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Serial No.` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Stock No.` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Tag No.` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Comments` varchar(255) default NULL,
      `Description` varchar(255) default NULL,
      FULLTEXT KEY `Model` (`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description`)
     )";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO $temp (
        id,
        Model,
        Make,
        Year,
        `Loc.`,
        `Sale Price`,
        `Serial No.`,
        `Tag No.`,
        Comments,
        Description
        )

        (
        (SELECT null,`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description` FROM ag_auger_and_grain_handling WHERE Status='IN' or Status='OF'
            UNION ALL
        SELECT null,`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description` FROM ag_combine WHERE Status='IN' or Status='OF'
            UNION
        SELECT null,`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description` FROM ag_tractor WHERE Status='IN' or Status='OF')
        )
    )";

?>
```

Here is the error I'm receiving:

> Could Not Perform Query Because: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO search_20121215094411 ( id,
>   Model, Make, Year, `Loc.`, `' at line 14

I can only guess it has something to do with the unconventional column names (Loc., Sale Price, etc.). These were set by a previous programmer and not I can make any changes to them.

Comment: Are you using the old `mysql_query()` API? With the older drivers, it does not support multiple statements in a single query call.  You must first execute the `CREATE TABLE`, then execute the `INSERT` separately.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra `)`

```
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO $temp (
    id,
    Model,
    Make,
    Year,
    `Loc.`,
    `Sale Price`,
    `Serial No.`,
    `Tag No.`,
    Comments,
    Description
    )

    (
    (SELECT null,`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description` FROM ag_auger_and_grain_handling WHERE Status='IN' or Status='OF'
        UNION ALL
    SELECT null,`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description` FROM ag_combine WHERE Status='IN' or Status='OF'
        UNION
    SELECT null,`Model`,`Make`,`Year`,`Loc.`,`Sale Price`,`Serial No.`,`Stock No.`,`Tag No.`,`Comments`,`Description` FROM ag_tractor WHERE Status='IN' or Status='OF')
    )
";
```

Comment: No, the table name is `search`, and table identifiers are not single quoted in MySQL.

Comment: Now you're missing the table name entirely.  a column list belongs in `()`.

Comment: Yes, and you are _still_ missing a table name in the `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2,3)` syntax. The table name should not be `()` enclosed.

Comment: No - you still have single quotes around the table name `'$temp'` which MySQL will interpret as a string literal. The OP's problem is attempting to execute 2 statements in one call, which is not supported.  It is not a syntactic error.

Comment: Yes but it still is wrong, and still isn't going to help. There is no `VALUES` keyword in an [`INSERT ... SELECT` statment.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Update did not work. receiving Could Not Perform Query Because: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO search_20121215110245 ( id, Model, Make, Year, `' at line 14              Sounds like I'm out of luck with multiple statements?

Comment: Would I be better off running the search using multiple selects vs. trying to move everything over to a temp table?

Comment: the last thing i can say is try use other query `$sql2` and run the insert into alone

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after the parenthesis of the create part of the sql, or just before the insert.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your "INSERT INTO $temp" line is not inserting the contents of $temp but actually using $temp as the table name.  Try something like this:

$sql="INSERT INTO ".$temp." (....

Answer (score 0):

When insert into temporary table with "union", you should create alias for table "union"

```
insert into temp_table (select * from (select * from table_a union select * from table_b) as table_alias)
```